# Apache mod_rewrite help on shared server

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using a shared hosting server with multiple domains, and my main .htaccess (inside the **public_html/** directory) redirects all traffic to the server to my main domain (fine). The problem becomes now that I have Wordpress running on the main domain that the subfolder is being included in the `%{REQUEST_URI}` variable. So my .htaccess code:

```
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}/index.php?%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

moves:

http://www.tonydiloreto.com/about/

to:

https://www.tonydiloreto.com/?/tonydiloreto/about/

(I put the `?` in there so I could see what is being stored in the variable). My question is, how do I use regex to remove the additional **/tonydiloreto** from the `%{REQUEST_URI}` variable when Rewriting? If this were PHP I would do:

```
$new_url = str_replace("/tonydiloreto", "", %{REQUEST_URI});
```

If that makes sense. If you want to see what I'm talking about just go to my site now (tonydiloreto.com) and put anything after a trailing slash.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure what the issue here is... You simply specify a request rule which captures only part of the uri. There are millions of examples for this...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/tonydiloreto/(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/index.php?$1 [L,R=301]
```

This is documented, obviously: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Note: the above is the version for the host configuration. If you really have to use `.htaccess` style files, then you have to remove the leading slash (`/`) from the pattern, since such files work on relative URIs. `.htaccess` style files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and *really* slow the server down.

Comment: So feel like an idiot here but did some more Googling (really wanted to achieve this without) but found the pattern I was looking for:

    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://tonydiloreto.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Very similar to what @arkascha posted above, and thank you for taking a stab at this.